# Does the creation account describing the position of the sun, moon, and stars contradict modern science?

Tags: genesis, creation

> Then God said: "Let there be an **expanse** between the waters, and let there be a division between the waters and the waters." Then God went on to make the **expanse** and divided the waters beneath the **expanse** from the waters above the **expanse**. And it was so. God called the **expanse** Heaven. (Gen. 1:6-8)

Here the Scriptures clearly state that there are waters above and that the space between the waters below it is called an **expanse** (heaven). Psalms 148:4 confirms these waters above:

> Praise him, O highest heavens And waters above the heavens.

After the creation of this expanse between two great bodies of water we see where God puts the sun, moon, ("and also") the stars:

> Then God said: "Let there be luminaries **in the expanse** of the heavens to make a division between the day and the night, and they will serve as signs for seasons and for days and years. They will serve as luminaries **in the expanse** of the heavens to shine upon the earth." And it was so. And God went on to make the two great luminaries, the greater luminary for dominating the day and the lesser luminary for dominating the night, *and also the stars*. Thus God put them **in the expanse** of the heavens to shine upon the earth and to dominate by day and by night and to make a division between the light and the darkness. (Gen. 1:14-18)

This is the *very same* "expanse" described in Genesis 1:6-8. There is no "outer space" described here or anywhere else in Scripture. Note that the stars are created almost as if they are an afterthought ("also the stars"), whereas the sun and moon are described as "great" luminaries which dominate. This contradicts modern cosmology which sees the sun as just an average star with other stars being more massive and greater than the sun. Modern "heliocentric" cosmology does not teach that the sun, moon, and stars are contained in an "expanse" between two great bodies of water.

Comment: Would you indicate which translation(s) you are using?

Comment: The answer is yes.  God founded the earth upon the waters (Psa. 25:1-2).  And, see post at my blog, Is the Earth Hanging Upon Nothing" here: https://shreddingtheveil.org/2021/02/01/is-the-earth-hanging-upon-nothing/

Answer (score 0):

The record in Gen 1:1-2:3 is written from a purely phenomenological point of view - that of an observer sitting on the earth watch everything.  It is not intended to be a scientific or cosmological statement; simply a series of events that occurred.

Thus, there is nothing wrong with saying that we see light in our atmosphere (from the sun, moon and stars) any more than saying that the sun rises and sets when in reality it is due to the rotation of the earth!

Now, the record in Gen 1 does not actually say that the sun, moon and stars exist in our atmosphere.  The record is careful to never mention those words; it only mentions the light from them as existing in our atmosphere, the "expanse" between the "waters above and the waters below.  See appendix below for a fuller explanation.

**APPENDIX - Genesis 1 Structure and Message.**

Understanding the creation account in Genesis involves the three key concepts listed in Gen 1:2

> Now the earth was (1) formless/chaotic and (2) void/empty, and (3) darkness was over the surface
> of the deep. And the Spirit of God was hovering over the surface of
> the waters.

Note the three significant words here:

1. תֹּהוּ (tohu) = formlessness, chaotic
2. בֹּהוּ (bohu) = emptiness
3. חשֶׁךְ (choshek) = darkness

See also Jer 4:23. The the succeeding account of creation of our world, God sets about giving it form/shape, filling it and banishing darkness.

Thus, God's first act is separate light from darkness by providing light.

[Note: I do not thing God actually created light at this moment because light has always been integral to God's existence as per 1 John 1:5.]

The six days of creation naturally fall into two sets of three:

**Days 1-3 - Separation/forming**

- day 1: God separates light from darkness and thus creates day/night
- day 2: God separates waters above from the waters below and thus creates the "heavens"
- day 3: God separates dry land ("earth") from seas and creates vegetation

**Days 4-6 - Population/filling**

- day 4: God places lights in the day and lights in the night
- day 5: God places birds in the heavens and creatures in the sea
- day 6: God places animals on the land and creates humans

1. Each day follows the strict formula, “And God said, ‘Let…’ …And there was evening and morning – the nth day.”  Thus, the first day of creation week begins in Gen 1:3, and the sixth day ends with Gen 1:31.  That is, Gen 1:2 is not part of the first day of creation activity.
2. In all but day 2 we also have the phrase, “And God saw that it was good (Gen 1:4, 10, 12, 18, 21, 25, 31) scattered through the text as well.
3. The two halves of creation week follow the same pattern.  The first half mostly concerns the act of separating (eg, waters above from waters below, light from darkness, land from sea, etc.), while the second half mostly concerns populating these separated habitats with living creatures or lights (the sun and moon are not explicitly mentioned).  This directly follows the pattern set up in Gen 1:2 where the earth is declared, “tohu and bohu” = formless and empty; God then proceeds to form and fill.
4. There are three phases of creation involving light, water, and dry ground.  Each required two steps separated by three days.  In the case of the land (the third phase of day 3 and day 6), two distinct creation acts are recorded each time, each terminated by the declaration that the result was good: on day 3 it is the separation of dry land from the water and then the creation of vegetation; on day 6 God made the land produce animals, and then the land (or soil Gen 2:7) was made to produce mankind.
5. The creation of the sun and moon is not recorded in this passage.  All that is stated is that God created lights in the expanse of the heaven (“sky” NIV, not outer space or the starry heaven), which according to Gen 1:6 is what separated the waters below (what became on day 3 rivers, lakes and seas) from the waters above (presumably the source of dew, rain and snow in the atmosphere).  Hebrew has perfectly good words for “sun” (שֶׁמֶשׁ shemesh) and “moon” (יָרֵחַ yareach) that the author obviously goes to some trouble to avoid using.
6. The passage contains several nomenclature or definition statements which are introduced by the phrase, “God called the…”.  This occurs for “day” and “night” (1:4), the “sky” or “heaven” (1:8), and the “land” or “earth” and the “seas” (1:10).  All these definition statements occur in the first three days only.  The naming of the living creatures was (presumably) to be left to Adam (2:19).
7. Further, there is no record (in Gen 1:1–2:3) of God creating planet Earth on any of the six days.  Nor is there any record of creating the water covering the planet – this was apparently all done before the first day of creation week which began in V3.  Thus, at the beginning of the first day of creation week, the Earth consisted of a “formless”, planet covered in water, totally lifeless and dark, over which the Spirit of God was moving (Gen 1:2).
8. Gen 1 is written from a phenomenological point of view - what an observer would simply see. It is NOT a scientific nor astronomical record. This is reinforced with passages like Eccl 1:5 about the sun and moon rising and setting and hurrying back again.
9. The fact that the sun produces its own light and the moon is a reflector of light (as we now know from astronomical analysis) is quite irrelevant to the record of Gen 1 because all that matters is that they are both sources of light for the inhabitants on earth. The stars are also sources of light as also recorded elsewhere, such as Eze 32:7, Jer 31:35, etc.
10. One of the several functions of the Gen 1 record is as type of salvation. God takes a world that (Gen 1:2) “tohu and bohu and hosek” = formless and void and dark; and by the end of the record we have, (v31) “And God looked upon all that He had made, and indeed, it was very good.” That is, we have the opposite - form, value and brightness!
11. It is not necessary for the author of a Bible passage to fully understand what is being revealed. We see this spectacularly in passages like Dan 8:27 and others. Thus, it is possible that the author was inspired to write the passage in the style and vocabulary they did to avoid misconceptions and unfounded claims.
12. The “vault” or “firmament” (רָקִיעַ raqia) is called heavens (שָׁמַיִם shamayim) Gen 1:8 and represents the space between the waters below and waters above.
13. The Bible writers of Gen 1 makes no attempt to distinguish between what we now call the atmosphere and outer space beyond the atmosphere - they had no language nor understanding of these things and it did not matter to them. Heaven was anything above the earth or soil (where crops were grown). Birds flew in the heaven (Gen 1:20, 26, 28, 30, 2:19, 20, 6:7, etc); water came from above the heavens (Gen 1:6, 7, 7:11, 8:2, etc); the sun, moon and stars existed in the heavens (Gen 1:14), etc.
14. Similarly, there is no concept of “planet earth” in Gen 1 - it is entirely foreign to the entire Bible. “earth” (אֶרֶץ erets) is simply dry, arable land (Gen 1:10) that makes agriculture possible.
15. It is very significant that in the creation record of Gen 1 -

- The heavens are created on day #2 (Gen 1:8)
- The earth is created in day #3 (Gen 1:10)

Therefore, a simple reading of Gen 1:1–2:3 suggests that a formless, worthless, dark, lifeless, watery planet already existed at (ie, before) the beginning of creation week.  This suggests that God had previously created it – a suggestion supported by Job 38:4-7, “Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? … Who laid its cornerstone while the morning stars and all the sons of God shouted for joy?”  Thus, other life forms existed elsewhere in the universe (apart from God) who witnessed the creation of the Earth during the planet’s very foundation.

Comment: God saw…not from a position of sitting on the earth, but from looking upon the work as it takes place.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of creation which places the earth in existence before the stars, sun, and moon seemingly does not agree with modern science. Of course, this sequence also contradicts what was known at the time it was written. The idea plant life could exist on the earth without the sun is contrary to all human knowledge.

However, modern science has confirmed the accuracy of the sequence which states the moon did not orbit the earth at first and that the weather patterns (the seasons) which exist today are based upon the relationship of the sun, earth, and moon. It may not be stated directly, but it is accurate to say the Bible correctly shows the current orbit of the earth is dependent on the combined mass of the earth and moon.

Furthermore, modern scientific theory believes heavy elements did not form directly  from the Big Bang. Supposedly elements heavier than hydrogen and helium formed in stars and were dispersed when the stars died. Therefore, the Biblical account should be seen as accurately placing the heavy elements found **before** the objects created to give **light** to the earth:

> <sup>14</sup> And God said, “Let there be lights in the expanse of the heavens to separate the day from the night. And let them be for signs and for seasons, and for days and years, <sup>15</sup> and let them be lights in the expanse of the heavens **to give light upon the earth**.” And it was so. <sup>16</sup> And God made the two great lights—the greater light to rule the day and the lesser light to rule the night—and the stars. <sup>17</sup> And God set them in the expanse of the heavens to give light on the earth, <sup>18</sup> to rule over the day and over the night, and to separate the light from the darkness. And God saw that it was good. <sup>19</sup> And there was evening and there was morning, the fourth day. (ESV)

The emphasis of the fourth day is the effect the sun, moon, and stars will have on the earth which is already in existence. In other words, modern science has essentially plagiarized the Biblical sequence of heavy elements needed to form the earth followed by later stars which currently give light to the earth.

Obviously, the presence of these accurate statements cannot result from  human knowledge and if there are contradictions between modern science and what is found in the Bible, the problem lies with science. In fact, the history of science is one of continual stream of "discoveries." Each new "discovery" is also an admission that which was previously believed was incorrect; old books are discarded and replaced. The Bible never changes and, interestingly, many discoveries result in changes to the theories which, like the sequence of heavy elements and stars giving light, agree with the sequence found in Genesis.